# edit/delete record in repeat region in php

Tags: php, edit

This is the code which generates the record set displayed. I want to `edit/delete` by clicking within a particular record and linking to a `edit.php` and `delete.php` page.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']))
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM casedt WHERE AdvUser= '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."' &&  FileNo = $fileno ";
    $result= mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
    #$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo 'Advocate UserID : '.$row['AdvUser'];
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>File No.</th><th>Next Dt</th><th>Comments</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo "</td><td>".$row["FileNo"]."</td><td>".$row["NextDt"]."</td><td>".$row["Comments"]."</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";           
    }

}
```

The table looks something like this:

[image: this].

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this, is creating a HyperLink tag `<a>`, which if the PHP file is relative to the file you are in now, can be defined as simple as:

```
<a href="edit.php">Edit</a>
```

Which will make the final code look like this, assuming the id column is named `Id` else change the `$row["Id"]` part:

```
echo "</td><td>".$row["FileNo"]."</td><td>".$row["NextDt"]."</td><td>".$row["Comments"]."</td><td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row["Id"]."'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row["Id"]."'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
```

What you are doing is passing a variable via the url, so `https://google.dk?id=2` would parse id 2 to the page you are linking, this variable can be fetched with this call, which should be added in edit.php and delete.php:

```
$_GET["id"]
```

If you file is in a different folder you can reference it with the path name:

```
<a href="/cms/edit.php">Edit</a>
```

Or if the `PHP` script is in a subfolder you can go up the folder tree like this:

```
<a href="../edit.php">Edit</a>
```

Comment: From where the record id will be given in the edit or delete.php page for a particular record.  Both record is for same file but for a different date.  However it also give a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the guidance